# Output a multidimensional array in groups

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional array of data which represents the list of users that are connected to our servers. Each array contains information about a connection. The same user could be connected to any number of ports on different servers.

```
Array(  [0] => Array(
            [0] => serverA
            [1] => port1,
            [2] => user1,
            [3] => ip1
        ),
        [1] => Array(
            [0] => serverB
            [1] => port2,
            [2] => user2,
            [3] => ip2
            ),
        [2] => Array(
            [0] => serverC
            [1] => port1,
            [2] => user3,
            [3] => ip3
            ),  
        [3] => Array(
            [0] => serverA
            [1] => port1,
            [2] => user4,
            [3] => ip4
            ),  
        [4] => Array(
            [0] => serverB
            [1] => port4,
            [2] => user5,
            [3] => ip5
            ),  
        [5] => Array(
            [0] => serverC
            [1] => port1,
            [2] => user6,
            [3] => ip6
            ),
        [6] => Array(
            [0] => serverA
            [1] => port2,
            [2] => user7,
            [3] => ip7
            ),              
)
```

I need to group by first the servers and then the ports and print out a list showing the connected users for each server and port as below:

```
ServerA
    port1
        user1,ip1
        user4,ip4
    port2
        user7,ip2
ServerB
    port2
        user2,ip2
    port4
        user5,ip5
ServerC
    port1
        user3,ip3
        user6,ip6
```

I'm confused as to how to approach this. Should I be using a multidimensional array sort  function (e.g. array_multisort) or should I be building a new array? An examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new array where you summarize the data and then print it in the required format:

```
$newArr = array();

foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
        if(!isset($newArr[$v[0]][$v[1]])) {
                $newArr[$v[0]][$v[1]] = array();
        }
        $newArr[$v[0]][$v[1]][] = array($v[2],$v[3]);
}

foreach($newArr as $k => $v) {
        echo $k,"\n";
        foreach($v as $k1 => $v1) {
                echo "\t$k1\n";
                foreach($v1 as $k2 => $v2) {
                        echo "\t\t", $v2[0],",",$v2[1],"\n";
                }
        }

        echo "\n";
}
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/Fz67v)

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is an impossible array. Because in an array the array key must be unique, so you wont be able to have two values for `serverA`

you have

```
[serverA] => Array (
        [0] => port1,
        [1] => user1,
        [2] => ip1
        ),
[serverA] => Array (
        [0] => port1,
        [1] => user4,
        [2] => ip4
        ),
[serverA] => Array (
        [0] => port2,
        [1] => user7,
        [2] => ip7
        ),
```

Please check the array and re-phrase the question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you were actually gonig to use an array for this, you would want to use associative arrays exclusively, with your port names as keys. However, this would only give you a one-to-one relationship between ports and users, and you want multiple users per port.

Honestly, you're going to need to create a PHP [Object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) for this. What I would do is represent a server with my object, with an array for each port. That way, you could store more than one user per port. Additonally, once you did this, you could write a method to parse through all of the arrays and organize it the way you need it.

Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

I would build a new array:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($old_array as $user) {
    //create new server entry, not 100% sure if it's really needed
    if(!isset($new_array[$user[0]])) $new_array[$user[0]] = array();

    //build the new array
    $new_array[$user[0]][$user[1]] = array($user[2], $user[3]);
}

print_r($new_array);
```